# UIScrollview not working when coming back from another view controller ( After pop)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

In a Viewcontroller there is a scrollview and inside that Scrollview there are some other view. When I am on that page it works perfectly. But when I push a view controller and then come back on that ViewController after doing a pop operation, then the Viewcontroller behaves strangely.

It doesn't scroll and also it also doesn't take any action on any button, it becomes unresponsive.

I have done the whole design in Storyboard, no code used.

Could you please tell me what went wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you set auto layout?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set an auto layout for the scroll view. And in the property indicator please check you have enabled user interaction. Scrolling enabled.

[image]